# mysqli_query returns null/false

Tags: php, database, mysqli, server

I am connected to a database and when I try and get the data stored in it using `mysqli_query` it doesn't work. When I echo the `$result` nothing shows up. When I use `var_dump($result)` I get `bool(false). By the way, the connection is working. Why isn't it working?

I have tried to change the names of the variables, I have read a lot of Q&A from other people and I can't figure out why is it not working.

```
<?php 
    require('database/dbconnection.php');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    var_dump($result);

    $usersDate = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    var_dump($usersDate);

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I expected to get the data and var_dump() it. But I cant because the query doesn't work.

$conn is the var I got when I required the `dbconnection.php` file

Comment: and if you do a var_dump of the $conn param after your require, what do you get then?

Comment: False is usually from something failing. Are you sure your connection is made? How are you sure. Is the users table created?

Comment: Try checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your query to see what it's returning.

Comment: Also, `echo` and `var_dump` treat false vastly different that is why on is blank echo converts false to a string false or blank  where var_dumb cares about type. You are not getting null just false outputted differently.